# Design database for real estate property management?

Tags: database-design

I have design this database diagram to real estate property management just I want to see if I get it right especially the relation between properties and finances because I made it one(property) to many(finances"bank loans")?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "got it right"?  The design of the database would work how you have it if there is a requirement to have multiple finance rows for each Properties row.  That is not opinion, it is a feature of your design.

Answer (score 3):

Properties can be resold multiple times, refinanced multiple times, have multiple loans/cash financing options per, be sublet/subdivided, have to follow government reporting requirements for all of that, etc. You need a thorough understanding of the business and proper specifications; the fact that you asked the question you have asked suggests to me that either you don't, and/or that you lack experience in the biz. Also, "property" is the singular of "properties", so, "propertyID".

Answer (score 1):

your diagram looks good, I assume that you are going to expand on the tables that you have as you develop this diagram more.

I would pull out the Purchase information into their own table.

also addresses should be their own table as well that way you don't duplicate data when a user moves into a property. you can just use the Address ID.